# How to know what applications have listening OSC/MIDI ports?

Tags: javascript, port, processing, midi, osc

I want to connect a GUI I developed in Processing via OSC/MIDI with software that receives OSC/MIDI (Resolume Arena, Ableton, TouchDesigner, etc) in my local machine. The problem is that I want people to choose what they want to connect to, and instead of setting up IP and PORT, they just choose the application they want to talk to.

So, I imagine I will need to list the ports and applications that are listening or waiting for OSC/MIDI to arrive, but I don't know how to make this. All the OSC monitors that I found (i.e  [OSC Data Monitor](https://www.kasperkamperman.com/blog/processing-code/osc-datamonitor/)), check the sent OSC messages, but I wanna know what applications and ports are able to receive them.

Answer (score 1):

For OSC, you can't.  There are no real standards for OSC service discovery.

For MIDI, you can enumerate the MIDI ports on the device, but there are no standards to know what is connected on the other end.

Comment: Great! "Service discovery" was the concept I was looking for. So, I came across this "[ZeroConfig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking)" approach, and apparently, there is a way to make OSC service discovery. Even [touchOSC](https://hexler.net/docs/touchosc-configuration-connections-osc) is sort of using it. So now the question would be: Is there any way to do ZeroConf to discover local OSC services in Processing or Javascript based desktop applications?